Lottie animation as mask-image
Is it possible to use a lottie animation as a mask-image property on an image?
This is my code:


const newData = {
  "v": "5.10.2",
  "fr": 60,
  "ip": 0,
  "op": 61,
  "w": 500,
  "h": 500,
  "nm": "Zeichenfläche – 2",
  "ddd": 0,
  "assets": [],
  "layers": [{
    "ddd": 0,
    "ind": 1,
    "ty": 4,
    "nm": "211120_Birgit-Brandis_1216_AS72265r",
    "sr": 1,
    "ks": {
      "o": {
        "a": 0,
        "k": 100,
        "ix": 11
      },
      "r": {
        "a": 0,
        "k": 0,
        "ix": 10
      },
      "p": {
        "a": 0,
        "k": [250, 250, 0],
        "ix": 2,
        "l": 2
      },
      "a": {
        "a": 0,
        "k": [182.5, 181.999, 0],
        "ix": 1,
        "l": 2
      },
      "s": {
        "a": 0,
        "k": [100, 100, 100],
        "ix": 6,
        "l": 2
      }
    },
    "ao": 0,
    "shapes": [{
      "ty": "gr",
      "it": [{
        "ind": 0,
        "ty": "sh",
        "ix": 1,
        "ks": {
          "a": 1,
          "k": [{
            "i": {
              "x": 0.05,
              "y": 1
            },
            "o": {
              "x": 0.5,
              "y": 0
            },
            "t": 0,
            "s": [{
              "i": [
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [-1.361, -1.076],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0]
              ],
              "o": [
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 4.649],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0]
              ],
              "v": [
                [365, 247.614],
                [349.777, 152.992],
                [297.992, 152.991],
                [312.734, 84.458],
                [312.734, 0.162],
                [265.372, 0.162],
                [250.757, 0.162],
                [181.461, 0.152],
                [65.961, 0.002],
                [35.985, 0.001],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 126.637],
                [2.322, 136.401],
                [14.262, 145.847],
                [15.552, 154.496],
                [17.362, 166.638],
                [17.362, 166.64],
                [0.047, 166.64],
                [0.047, 286.072],
                [0.047, 362.438],
                [14.731, 362.697],
                [39.602, 363.136],
                [253.728, 363.836],
                [253.728, 363.635],
                [365, 363.999]
              ],
              "c": true
            }]
          }, {
            "t": 60,
            "s": [{
              "i": [
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0.303, -3.151],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [-3.261, -3.473],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0]
              ],
              "o": [
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 4.649],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [5.308, 5.652],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 0]
              ],
              "v": [
                [365, 247.614],
                [365.027, 153.242],
                [364.992, 152.991],
                [365.234, 85.958],
                [365.234, 50.412],
                [343.52, 32.444],
                [343.007, 24.162],
                [301.211, 24.162],
                [63.711, 24.25],
                [35.485, 0],
                [0, 0],
                [0, 126.637],
                [-0.053, 137.526],
                [0.012, 147.222],
                [0.052, 154.746],
                [0.237, 166.763],
                [0.112, 166.765],
                [0.047, 166.64],
                [0.047, 278.999],
                [22.297, 348.688],
                [27.011, 359.347],
                [39.602, 363.761],
                [253.727, 363.836],
                [325.977, 364.01],
                [365, 345.999]
              ],
              "c": true
            }]
          }],
          "ix": 2
        },
        "nm": "Path 1",
        "mn": "ADBE Vector Shape - Group",
        "hd": false
      }, {
        "ty": "fl",
        "c": {
          "a": 0,
          "k": [0, 0, 0, 1],
          "ix": 4
        },
        "o": {
          "a": 0,
          "k": 100,
          "ix": 5
        },
        "r": 1,
        "bm": 0,
        "nm": "Fill 1",
        "mn": "ADBE Vector Graphic - Fill",
        "hd": false
      }, {
        "ty": "tr",
        "p": {
          "a": 0,
          "k": [0, 0],
          "ix": 2
        },
        "a": {
          "a": 0,
          "k": [0, 0],
          "ix": 1
        },
        "s": {
          "a": 0,
          "k": [100, 100],
          "ix": 3
        },
        "r": {
          "a": 0,
          "k": 0,
          "ix": 6
        },
        "o": {
          "a": 0,
          "k": 100,
          "ix": 7
        },
        "sk": {
          "a": 0,
          "k": 0,
          "ix": 4
        },
        "sa": {
          "a": 0,
          "k": 0,
          "ix": 5
        },
        "nm": "Transform"
      }],
      "nm": "211120_Birgit-Brandis_1216_AS72265r",
      "np": 2,
      "cix": 2,
      "bm": 0,
      "ix": 1,
      "mn": "ADBE Vector Group",
      "hd": false
    }],
    "ip": 0,
    "op": 3600,
    "st": 0,
    "ct": 1,
    "bm": 0
  }],
  "markers": []
}

var params = {
  container: document.getElementById('lottie'),
  renderer: 'svg',
  loop: false,
  autoplay: false,
  animationData: newData,
  rendererSettings: {
    preserveAspectRatio: 'none',
    id: 'mask',
  },
};

var anim;

anim = bodymovin.loadAnimation(params);

let lottie = document.querySelector('#lottie')

function playLottie(direction) {
  if (direction == 'f') {
    anim.setDirection(1)
  } else {
    anim.setDirection(-1)
  }
  anim.play()
}
lottie.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  playLottie('f')
})
lottie.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  playLottie('b')
})
#container {
  display: flex;
}

#lottie {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
}

#masked {
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-image: url(#mask);
  mask-size: 100% 100%;
  mask-position: center;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/5.9.1/lottie.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/500" />
  <div id="lottie"></div>
  <img id="masked" src="https://picsum.photos/300/500" />
</div>



Alternatively see this codepen:
https://codepen.io/jacquesknie/pen/WNVGdWW
The first HTML-element is an image, the second element is a lottie-animation which starts its animation on mouseover, the third element is the same image with the lottie-animation as its mask-image. Unfortunately this doesn't work. The idea is to have an animated mask on the image on mouseover.
Is there any way to make this work? Maybe even with a very different approach?
Thanks in advance!

Could you check your codepen which doesn't seem to have anything with id masked. Alternatively, and preferably, make your code into a runnable snippet and check that it really shows the problem - use <> in the editor here.

The codepen should have a third image with the id "masked", which is not visible in the rendered result, because it is fully masked by the lottie-animation. That is the problem. If I try to create a runnable snipped the lottie animation doesn't work at all, so I think snippets do not cover that functionality.

You can, but you need to ensure you get/create a SVG <mask> element.
In short you can reference a mask via:

element ID: element must be <mask>
dataURL: you can add a complete SVG and choose whether luminance or opacity is defining transparency

In this case you can move the dynamically created animated SVG to a new <mask> element.


// add event listeners to image
masked.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  playLottie("f");
});
masked.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  playLottie("b");
});

// get SVG
let lottieSvg = lottie.querySelector('svg')

//hide lottie svg
lottieSvg.setAttribute('style', `width:0; height:0; position:absolute;`)
let ns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';

// create SVG mask
let maskEl = document.createElementNS(ns, 'mask')
lottieSvg.append(maskEl)

// add mask bg
let rect = document.createElementNS(ns, 'rect')
rect.setAttribute('fill', '#000')
rect.setAttribute('width', '100%')
rect.setAttribute('height', '100%')
maskEl.append(rect)
maskEl.id = 'mask';

// move outermost group to mask
let gMain = lottie.querySelector('g')
maskEl.append(gMain)
gMain.removeAttribute('clip-path')

let path = lottie.querySelector('path')
path.setAttribute('fill', '#fff')
body {
  background: #ccc
}

#masked {
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-image: url(#mask);
  mask-size: 100% 100%;
  mask-position: center;
  mask-mode: luminance;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/5.9.1/lottie.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="lottie"></div>
  <img id="masked" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/300/500" />
</div>

<script>
  const newData = {
    v: "5.10.2",
    fr: 60,
    ip: 0,
    op: 61,
    w: 500,
    h: 500,
    nm: "Zeichenfläche – 2",
    ddd: 0,
    assets: [],
    layers: [{
      ddd: 0,
      ind: 1,
      ty: 4,
      nm: "211120_Birgit-Brandis_1216_AS72265r",
      sr: 1,
      ks: {
        o: {
          a: 0,
          k: 100,
          ix: 11
        },
        r: {
          a: 0,
          k: 0,
          ix: 10
        },
        p: {
          a: 0,
          k: [250, 250, 0],
          ix: 2,
          l: 2
        },
        a: {
          a: 0,
          k: [182.5, 181.999, 0],
          ix: 1,
          l: 2
        },
        s: {
          a: 0,
          k: [100, 100, 100],
          ix: 6,
          l: 2
        }
      },
      ao: 0,
      shapes: [{
        ty: "gr",
        it: [{
            ind: 0,
            ty: "sh",
            ix: 1,
            ks: {
              a: 1,
              k: [{
                  i: {
                    x: 0.05,
                    y: 1
                  },
                  o: {
                    x: 0.5,
                    y: 0
                  },
                  t: 0,
                  s: [{
                    i: [
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [-1.361, -1.076],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0]
                    ],
                    o: [
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 4.649],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0]
                    ],
                    v: [
                      [365, 247.614],
                      [349.777, 152.992],
                      [297.992, 152.991],
                      [312.734, 84.458],
                      [312.734, 0.162],
                      [265.372, 0.162],
                      [250.757, 0.162],
                      [181.461, 0.152],
                      [65.961, 0.002],
                      [35.985, 0.001],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 126.637],
                      [2.322, 136.401],
                      [14.262, 145.847],
                      [15.552, 154.496],
                      [17.362, 166.638],
                      [17.362, 166.64],
                      [0.047, 166.64],
                      [0.047, 286.072],
                      [0.047, 362.438],
                      [14.731, 362.697],
                      [39.602, 363.136],
                      [253.728, 363.836],
                      [253.728, 363.635],
                      [365, 363.999]
                    ],
                    c: true
                  }]
                },
                {
                  t: 60,
                  s: [{
                    i: [
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0.303, -3.151],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [-3.261, -3.473],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0]
                    ],
                    o: [
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 4.649],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [5.308, 5.652],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 0]
                    ],
                    v: [
                      [365, 247.614],
                      [365.027, 153.242],
                      [364.992, 152.991],
                      [365.234, 85.958],
                      [365.234, 50.412],
                      [343.52, 32.444],
                      [343.007, 24.162],
                      [301.211, 24.162],
                      [63.711, 24.25],
                      [35.485, 0],
                      [0, 0],
                      [0, 126.637],
                      [-0.053, 137.526],
                      [0.012, 147.222],
                      [0.052, 154.746],
                      [0.237, 166.763],
                      [0.112, 166.765],
                      [0.047, 166.64],
                      [0.047, 278.999],
                      [22.297, 348.688],
                      [27.011, 359.347],
                      [39.602, 363.761],
                      [253.727, 363.836],
                      [325.977, 364.01],
                      [365, 345.999]
                    ],
                    c: true
                  }]
                }
              ],
              ix: 2
            },
            nm: "Path 1",
            mn: "ADBE Vector Shape - Group",
            hd: false
          },
          {
            ty: "fl",
            c: {
              a: 0,
              k: [0, 0, 0, 1],
              ix: 4
            },
            o: {
              a: 0,
              k: 100,
              ix: 5
            },
            r: 1,
            bm: 0,
            nm: "Fill 1",
            mn: "ADBE Vector Graphic - Fill",
            hd: false
          },
          {
            ty: "tr",
            p: {
              a: 0,
              k: [0, 0],
              ix: 2
            },
            a: {
              a: 0,
              k: [0, 0],
              ix: 1
            },
            s: {
              a: 0,
              k: [100, 100],
              ix: 3
            },
            r: {
              a: 0,
              k: 0,
              ix: 6
            },
            o: {
              a: 0,
              k: 100,
              ix: 7
            },
            sk: {
              a: 0,
              k: 0,
              ix: 4
            },
            sa: {
              a: 0,
              k: 0,
              ix: 5
            },
            nm: "Transform"
          }
        ],
        nm: "211120_Birgit-Brandis_1216_AS72265r",
        np: 2,
        cix: 2,
        bm: 0,
        ix: 1,
        mn: "ADBE Vector Group",
        hd: false
      }],
      ip: 0,
      op: 3600,
      st: 0,
      ct: 1,
      bm: 0
    }],
    markers: []
  };

  var params = {
    container: document.getElementById("lottie"),
    renderer: "svg",
    loop: false,
    autoplay: false,
    animationData: newData,
    rendererSettings: {
      preserveAspectRatio: "none",
      id: "maskEl"
    }
  };

  var anim;

  anim = bodymovin.loadAnimation(params);

  let lottie = document.querySelector("#lottie");

  function playLottie(direction) {
    if (direction == "f") {
      anim.setDirection(1);
    } else {
      anim.setDirection(-1);
    }
    anim.play();
  }
</script>



You also need to bind the animation event with the masked element as the mask itself isn't rendered and therefore not introduce a hit-area.
masked.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  playLottie("f");
});

I highly recommend to first test masks (or clip-paths) with simplified HTML output before combining it with complex framework/library created elements.

Awesome, that works. I'm marking it as solved and thanks a lot!
